# How to get the Instagram Media_ID of video In Ios.?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, instagram, instagram-api

I'm am looking for the MediaID of an Instagram video which has been uploaded. It should look like
1234567894561231236_33215652

I use the instagram document @" https://www.instagram.com/developer/embedding/  but this are done by manually..?

I want this programatically using  Instagram API or any other way..?

please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this API:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/shortcode/{short-code}?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/#get_media_by_shortcode

`{short-code}` is the code in Instagram URL: for example `BOn2hFYjz5a` in `https://www.instagram.com/p/BOn2hFYjz5a/`

Comment: Thanks For your Ans, but how to create that  {short-code} URL in documentation ( https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/#get_media_by_shortcode) they give it but it is a Manual process na?

Comment: use the user media end point to get list of media from a user and get ids

Comment: I'm sharing the video on Insta from My videoMakerApp And I want to get the video ID For fetching the Like count. If I fetch the Media List Then how can shortlist that Particular video ID which I need..

Comment: how are u sharing video, using instagram video url ? show example

Comment: [self loadCameraRollAssetToInstagram:@"My_Video_Url_Here" andMessage:@"via BSHN"]

//Delegate Method
NSString *escString   = [assetsLibraryURL.absoluteString stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]]
    NSString *eCaption  = [message stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]]
    NSURL *URL  = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"instagram://library?AssetPath=%@&InstagramCaption=%@", eCaption]]
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:instagramURL]
/Share on app

Comment: Using the above code It open the Insta App & user shared the video... Is there any CallBack Url When user get the back when video shared successfully, like user Login On Insta webView and get back the response

Comment: No there is no way to get that info currently, if u know the username, you can check that user for recent media using API and check timestamp and get id (not 100% accurate, but is a workaround)

Comment: Thanks..!!! But Instagram recent media response Time stamp key look like this "created_time: "1483367654"". So how to do you  know, when you share these post. Can we can convert it into normal time.

Comment: convert current time to epoch time and compare with instagram created_time. here is tool for epoch time converter: http://www.epochconverter.com/ all programming languages support epoch time format